# Laravel - Registering a Decorator

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement Decorator Pattern in Laravel container for `Mailer` service. Following the syntax on [this page](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe#extending-a-class), as well as [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#binding).

I am registering the `MailerDecorator` in `AppServiceProvider`'s (which is registered in `app.php` config) `register` method.

```
$this->app->extend(Mailer::class, function ($mailer) {
    return new MailerDecorator($mailer);
});
```

Unfortunately, the Decorator is not registered and the app is still using the old implementation.

Is there a way to debug the container? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel Mailer class is binded with an alias of `mailer` so you can try registering the Decorator using `mailer` alias instead of `Mailer::class`.

```
$this->app->extend('mailer', function ($mailer) {
    return new MailerDecorator($mailer);
});
```